# Getting row or TreePath of JTree node that is not in the viewport

Tags: jscrollpane, jtree

I have a JTree and a custom renderer.

The JTree is a tree of ip addresses by switch and port number.

I have a graph of the ip addresses.

When the user clicks on a graph line, I try to update the JTree to show the line selected by the user.

If the ip selected by the user's mouse click in the graph, the renderer contains that node and other actions happen easily because the row and TreePath are available.

If the list of ip's is large and some are scrolled out of the viewport, I am having a problem finding out what the row or treenode is for the object/ip that I want to select and show in the viewport.

I have an ActionEvent in the JTree that gets some of the text that makes up the nodes' text, returned from getUserObject().

I don't know how to find the row or TreeNode.  If I could find them I could check if the row was visible and if not call makeVisible(treePath) - or use scrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect() and compare it to the rect of the treeNode.

Thanks for any tips or direction ... 
Jim

Comment: Just call `makeVisible(treePath)` every time, not much overhead if you're going on user interaction... If you're unhappy with it making your selection appear at the bottom of the list, call `makeVisible(treePath)` twice, once for the very last item in the tree and then again for the desired item, that should make it appear at the top!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in the following manner.

After expanding all the nodes I fill a hashmap that has ip as the key and row as the value.

When I get me event containing the ip, I look up the row in the hasmap.

This works whether the node/row is in the viewport or not.

As follows:

```
        if ( ipRowMap.containsKey( ip )) {
            row = ipRowMap.get( ip ); 
            TreePath tp = getPathForRow( row );
            Rectangle rtp = this.getPathBounds( tp );
            Rectangle rsp = scrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect();
            if ( !rtp.intersects( rsp)) {
                scrollPane.getViewport().scrollRectToVisible( rtp );
            }
        }
```

This works the first time, but not every time.

But that will be a new post if I can't solve that problem.  I think the scrollpane or viewport has changed in a way I am not handling.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better method for working with a JTree.

The method above works ok for JLists.

Since I have a map of rows, given the row number there is a JTree specific call of Component.

```
            scrollRowToVisible( row );
```

and the code becomes

```
    if ( ipRowMap.containsKey( ip )) {
        row = ipRowMap.get( ip ); 
        scrollRowToVisible( row );
    }
```